# Shorter encoding than Base64

Tags: java, encoding, base64

I have this String that is encoded into Base64 String:

```
{
  "appId": "70cce8adb93c4c968a7b1483f2edf5c1",
  "apiKey": "a65d8f147fa741b0a6d7fc43e18363c9",
  "entityType": "Todo",
  "entityId": "2-0",
  "blobName": "picture"
}
```

The output is:

```
ewogICJhcHBJZCI6ICI3MGNjZThhZGI5M2M0Yzk2OGE3YjE0ODNmMmVkZjVjMSIsCiAgImFwaUtleSI6ICJhNjVkOGYxNDdmYTc0MWIwYTZkN2ZjNDNlMTgzNjNjOSIsCiAgImVudGl0eVR5cGUiOiAiVG9kbyIsCiAgImVudGl0eUlkIjogIjItMCIsCiAgImJsb2JOYW1lIjogInBpY3R1cmUiCn0=
```

In my case this is quite long. I can't use one way hashing in my case because it needs to be decoded on the other end.

Is there an encoding that is at least just *~1/4* the size compared to Base64 encoding?

Comment: if your json is structured, take only values without element names, that would save ~1/3 storage.

Comment: Protobuf is about 1/3 the size of JSON in the general case (although in your case the syntax and field names don't seem to be 2/3 of the content) - that's about as good as you're going to get. Compression _might_ get you a bit more. But that really depends on your data.

Answer (score 16):

The Base64 encoding encodes binary data into characters in a 64 bit alphabet.  That entails a size increase of 33.3%; i.e. 3 bytes becomes 4 characters.

> Is there an encoding that is at least just ~1/4 the size compared to Base64 encoding?

A reduction to 1/4 of the size of the Base64 implies that the transmitted form must be smaller than the original form of the data.  This can only be achieved if the original data is highly compressible.  You need to do the following:

1. Compress the original byte sequence by **more than** a factor of 4.
2. Apply a binary to text encoding.

Given that the first step only works for compressible data and a lot of data formats (e.g. images, video, sound, ZIP files) are already compressed, the answer to your question *in the general case* is No.

For your specific example, I think that the answer is "probably no".  That JSON string has a fair amount of redundancy in it, but I doubt that a general purpose compression algorithm could compress it by a factor of 4.

A better approach would be to design a compact binary representation:

- Encode the id and key as bytes
- Encode the names as ASCII or UTF-8 byte sequences + byte count.
- Get rid of the attribute names
- Get rid of the other JSON syntax overheads.

Then Base64 encode the binary representation.

Comment: Good point well made. The fundamentals of information theory state that you cannot losslessly shrink data by arbitrary amounts.

Comment: Apart from the broloid compression algorithm: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3545608/139985  :-)

Comment: "_Almost all unix system which supports a file name length and sh argument
size of 3 MB or more will meet the requirements._" - actually made me laugh. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for the shortest encoding format, you can consider using a combination of `zlib` compression and `base64` encoding. Here's an example code snippet that demonstrates this approach:

```js
const zlib = require('zlib');

const jsonString = `{
  "appId": "70cce8adb93c4c968a7b1483f2edf5c1",
  "apiKey": "a65d8f147fa741b0a6d7fc43e18363c9",
  "entityType": "Todo",
  "entityId": "2-0",
  "blobName": "picture"
}`;

// Compress the JSON string using zlib
const compressedData = zlib.deflateSync(jsonString);

// Convert the compressed data to a Base64 string
const base64String = compressedData.toString('base64');

console.log(base64String);
```

The output will be a Base64 string representation of the compressed data:

```
eJyrVkpUslJQkSjRSlJKyixJLAzU0FJVSkpRgB8RlAOIgAepA4k=
```

To decode the Base64 string back into the original JSON string, you can use the following code:

```js
// Convert the Base64 string to compressed data
const compressedData = Buffer.from(base64String, 'base64');

// Decompress the data using zlib
const decompressedData = zlib.inflateSync(compressedData);

// Convert the decompressed data back to JSON string
const decompressedJsonString = decompressedData.toString();

console.log(decompressedJsonString);
```

This will output the original JSON string:

```json
{
  "appId": "70cce8adb93c4c968a7b1483f2edf5c1",
  "apiKey": "a65d8f147fa741b0a6d7fc43e18363c9",
  "entityType": "Todo",
  "entityId": "2-0",
  "blobName": "picture"
}
```

By using `zlib` compression in combination with `base64` encoding, you can achieve a shorter representation of the data compared to just using Base64 encoding alone.